# Правильно ли сделано изменение css стилей при скроллинге?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Есть код. Подскажите верна ли реализация?

Суть такая - есть шапка сайта которая имеет два класса с разными css стилями. При скроллинге вниз она меняет свои стили, а если поднять в начало страницы то получает исходные значения.

Вопрос такой: правильно ли реализован код (код работает)? Просто хочу узнать мнение.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  document.querySelector('#header');
  var el = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  if (el > 1) {
    document.querySelector('#header').classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#header').classList.remove("sticky");
  }
};
```

Comment: Не понятно, в чем великий смысл второй строки кода?

Comment: всё норм, только повторяющиеся вызовы заверните в указатель на объект DOM - переменную: var header = document.querySelector('#header'); и с ним уже работайте.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin, не очень-то норм, а вот полезных повторяющихся вызовов там как раз нет.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov А что именно не так я новый человек в js

Comment: @KirillKorushkin а что не так с моей второй строчкой кода?

Comment: а что в ней происходит, в этой строчке?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/metrics-window

Comment: @KirillKorushkin Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> window.onscroll = function() {
> ```

Лучше подписываться через `addEventListener`.

Ещё нет проверки, какой именно элемент прокручивается. В данном случае это некритично, но потенциально может вызывать лишние перерессчёты и влиять на производительность.

> ```
> document.querySelector('#header');
> ```

Бесполезный код.

> ```
> var el = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
> ```

Называть число (позицию скролла) элементом не следует.

> ```
> if (el > 1) {
> ```

0px и 1px считаются непрокрученными, а всё остальное - прокрученным?

Если это действительно то, что требуется, то я бы записал `>=2` (с учётом того, что число всегда целое), потому что иначе без комментария неясно, ошибка это, или так задумано.

Comment: а как передать начальное положение скрола? что бы убрать var el

Comment: не убрать надо, а переименовать просто